# Create my own implementation of take using zip, unzip, fst and list construction

Tags: haskell

I need to get the first n elements from a list in haskell but I cannot use the take function. In the example below I need to replace "take" using zip, unzip, fst and list construction. I'm really struggling with this, any pointers?

```
main = do
    let result = takeFirstN "test" 2
    putStrLn(result)

takeFirstN list nth = do
    take nth list
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how `zip` could be used to create a shorter list than `list`? (Don’t worry about what that list looks like for now.)

Comment: Hint: the list construction you want to perform could probably be done with `enumFromTo`.

Comment: @chepner `replicate` seems like a simpler suggestion. What does `enumFromTo` help with?

Comment: @amalloy I'm not sure I can answer that without giving too big a hint :) (But I mentioned it as it is intimately tied with the definition of one of the standard forms of a list literal.)

Comment: Why people are downvoting this posts?

Answer (score 1):

After some sleep and reading your pointers I've came to a solution.

```
main =
    do
    print (takeFirstNth "test" 3)

takeFirstNth list nth = fst (unzip (zip list [1..nth]))
```

Thanks for the nudges in the right direction :)